Can't downgrade Tensorflow Python package to 2.15.0
The model and code provided by Teachable Machine require Tensorflow 2.15.0 to work . However attempting to download that version with pip, I receive an error that only 2.16 and above is supported. The code works fine on Google Collab though. How can I fix this?
pip install tensorflow==2.15.0
Is what I tried

It would be helpful to know the Python version and OS. I suspect you're using Python 3.12, and tensorflow 2.15.0 doesn't have built distributions for 3.12.

https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/2.15.1/ Python :: 3.9, Python :: 3.10, Python :: 3.11.


As you can see in colab the version of python is 3.10.12, so you must install a similar version, such as 3.10.11. I recommend uninstalling a higher version of Python beforehand.
Once version 3.10.11 is installed, verify that no tensorflow package  is installed (with pip list).
Then install tensorflow with: pip install tensorflow==2.15.0.
Finally install the teachable-machine package with: pip install teachable-machine

Happy coding!
